# 12.10 won't boot on EFI

Tags: boot, upgrade, uefi

I had 12.04 LTS 32 bit alongside Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit. Windows uses EFI. When I noticed that I had Ubuntu in 32 bit I decided to install 12.10 64 bit. I wanted to install an upgrade to keep my settings of Thunderbird and Firefox (data is stored on Windows partitions). The installer found EFI but told me that something went wrong with GRUB. I used boot repair and got the following link:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/1507240

I hope someone can find the error and help me fix it. Thanks in advance.

Sincerely yours,

Zuversicht

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the 1st paragraph of https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: page was probably updated, 1st paragraph is now a meaningless introduction